# passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {} block not getting executed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local

I am new to MERN(Mongo,Express, React,Node) and am using it to create an app. I saw a tutorial on passport and implemented it exactly as shown in the tutorial but I keep getting "Bad Request" getting render on the screen.

In the course I took the instructor used passport for express-ejs, I just extrapolated that to react.

Based on the debugging I did - the passport.authenticate() function never gets executed. The hashed password and emailed gets logged to my mongo server, but it never gets authenticated. I spent a whole day trying to debug, but to of no avail.

Below is my enter server side code. **Localhost:5000 is my express server and localhost:3000 is the react server** any help would be greatly appreciated. Error code 400 btw

```
 * Require Dependencies 
 */
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

////////////////////////////// Get Request Block //////////////////////////////
app.get("/secrets", function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/secrets");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/register");
    }
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {

    User.register({ username: req.body.emailId }, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/error");
        } else {
            console.log("me");
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
                console.log("met1e1e");
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });

            // passport.authenticate('local', {
            //     successRedirect: '/secrets',
            //     failureRedirect: '/error',
            //     failureFlash: true
            // });
        }
    });

});

app.get("/error", function (req, res) {
   console.log("debug:wrkbj");
   res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/main");
});


app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log("Server live on port 5000.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your Schema to-
   const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password:String
   });
2. In your app.post("/register" ... section, put username as-
   { username: req.body.username }

Since your register method registers a new user wherein the email is stored in the username, you cannot use "email" in your userSchema. **You should also replace all "emailId" name attributes in your register.ejs file in views folder with "username".** This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.render("secrets");`in app.get("/secrets") route, instead of URL `res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/secrets");` it will work. No need to change to **username** instead of **email id**.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an if statement to catch if the user is exiting or not. Then it will be worked properly.

```
    if(user){
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function (){
      res.redirect("/secrets");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

compare this with your code

```
 app.get('/secrets', (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render("secrets");
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}); 
    User.register({ username: req.body.username }, 
    req.body.password).then(function(user) {
           if (user) {
               passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, 
    function() {
                   res.redirect("/secrets");
               })
          }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register")
    })
```